# Angularjs inifinity digest loop on AngularFire authentication

Tags: angularjs, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularjs-digest

Help! I want to know how to stop it? I have a problem with infinity digest loop after using angular ui-router & angularFire. I found that the loop keep falling into $stateChangeStart even login state is called. Here is my console log.

```
1476969257159 Start:   {} -> dashboard{}
Auth errorAUTH_REQUIRED
1476969259545 Start:   {} -> login{}
1476969260671 Start:   {} -> dashboard{}
Auth errorAUTH_REQUIRED
1476969263828 Start:   {} -> login{}
1476969266255 Start:   {} -> dashboard{}
```

I codes my ui-router this way

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError",function (ev,toSt,toPa,fromSt,fromPa,error) {
 // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireSignIn promise is rejected
    console.log("Auth error" + error);
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
         $state.go("login");
    }
 });
```

And

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', '/dashboard')
    .when('','/')
    .otherwise('/404');
```

States i have,

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard/dashboard.html'
    resolve: {
    // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
    // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the factory below
    "currentAuth": ["wifAuth", function(wifAuth) {
        // console.log ("dashboard check");
        // $requireSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
        // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
            return wifAuth.$requireSignIn();
            }]
        }
    })

    .state('login',{
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/auth/login.html',
    resolve: {
    // controller will not be loaded until $waitForSignIn resolves
    // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the factory below
    "currentAuth": ["wifAuth", function(wifAuth) {
        // console.log ("login check");
        // $waitForSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
            return wifAuth.$waitForSignIn();
            }]
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it by adding

> event.preventDefault ()

to halt dashboard state

```
 if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    //halt default event then initiate state go to new nested page
    event.preventDefault();

    // as of now, we go to login until landing template is up
    $state.go("landing");
    // $state.go("login");
 }
```